# Unable to have feature flag feature refreshed

Tags: azure-app-configuration

I've an issue where even if I set the expiration to low times, it's not applied

Here's the configuration on startup.cs

```
 appBuilder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
 {
     var appConfigurationConnectionString = appBuilder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureAppConfig");

     options.Connect(appConfigurationConnectionString).UseFeatureFlags(configure =>
         {
             configure.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
         })
         .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
         {
             refreshOptions.Register("hangfire-recurring_jobs-generate_sitemap", true);
             refreshOptions.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
         });
 });
```

And in my hangfire job configuration I use

```
      private async Task RegisterRecurringJobAsync<T>(
          string featureFlag,
          string jobName,
          Expression<Action<T>> methodCall,
          string cronExpression)
      {
          string cronExpressionToAssign;

          if (await _featureManager.IsEnabledAsync(featureFlag))
          {
              _logger.LogInformation("Registering job {JobName} with recurring: {CronExpression}", jobName, cronExpression);
              cronExpressionToAssign = cronExpression;
          }
          else
          {
              _logger.LogInformation("Registering job {JobName} with NO EXECUTION. Disabled by Appconfig.", jobName);
              cronExpressionToAssign = Cron.Never();
          }

          RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(methodCall, cronExpressionToAssign);
      }
```

Here even after the 1 minute passed it's still using the old value.

If I restart the application, it works correctly.

The strange thing I noticed using the debugger is that if I open the view watch I've

[image]

I don't know if those values are correct.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This answer should help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367669/azure-feature-flag-is-not-updating-after-cache-expiration

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here is that your Configuration is not being triggered to refresh.

If you're writing an ASP.NET app, ensure you have:

```cs
app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();
```

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core6x*

Or if it's .NET, ensure you're calling TryRefreshAsync or using some sort of middleware that will call it for you

```cs
await _refresher.TryRefreshAsync();
Console.WriteLine(_configuration["TestApp:Settings:Message"] ?? "Hello world!");
```

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x*

---

### Context

The library that handles the dynamic configurations (.AddAzureAppConfiguration()) is the [Provider Library](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration-DotnetProvider) which is separate from the [Feature Management Library](https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet).

To kick off a refresh, there is a middleware offered. The middleware is setup via `UseAzureAppConfiguration()` where it adds `AzureAppConfigurationRefreshMiddleware` to be invoked during http requests. This means `TryRefreshAsync` is called as an http request comes in. `TryRefreshAsync` does nothing if it's still within the cache expiration interval, otherwise it checks for a refresh and refreshes if needed. This means it's safe to call it multiple times.

Non http apps don't have a consistent workflow to hook to in the same way. So the current state is to leave it to the developer to trigger the refresh appropriately. If assumptions are made for when to refresh, it might cause changes mid-execution that might not make sense for the app.

Originally, a timer approach was used by the library and would update the config in a recurring way (which would work out of the box in your scenario). All this timer did was call `TryRefreshAsync` after a given amount of time. Unfortunately, this led to a large number of refreshes for stale apps and was removed.

Calling `TryRefreshAsync()` at the start of an execution is usually ideal, but if your app wants to refresh more often, then it can do so.

In regards to the options you set, I think the field names are slightly misleading. Those options are read by calls to `TryRefreshAsync`, but themselves don't kickoff the refresh.

Hope this helps!

Comment: excuse me , but in my case I don't have to deal with HttpRequest and having a timer acting as refresher would be better

Comment: You can setup your own timed refresh if you call TryRefreshAsync on a timer - just be aware that TryRefreshAsync will not actually do anything unless the cache expiration interval has expired. 
Additionally, you dont need to call `ConfigureRefresh` in your setup. Since you're only dealing with feature flags, you just need to call the `UseFeatureFlags` method. 
Also, you're setting the cache expiration interval to 1 minute, which is actually higher than the default interval of 30 seconds. You could simplify your code to:
`options.Connect(appConfigurationConnectionString).UseFeatureFlags();`

Comment: Why is it like this? The design seems fine. You can do this: 

.UseFeatureFlags(c => c.Select(appkey, "mylabel")
    .CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)

The under the covers there is a nice little snapshot deisgn that is scoped this means the flags will remain consister per that scope.

Simply when my timeout expires then read the value again.

This is literally what we have to do anyway..

Comment: Cause I have had to resort to this tom foolery:
.UseFeatureFlags(c =>
   c.Select(appkey, context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName))
   .Map(kv =>
   {
       options.ConfigureRefresh(c => c.Register(kv.Key, label: context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName));
       return ValueTask.FromResult(kv);
   });
Then have a "refresher" that will do this once I start my scope.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to refresh your Azure App Configuration values with a cache expiration of 1 minute. The core issue you're facing appears to stem from the fact that your configuration values aren't being automatically refreshed.

Here are a few pointers to consider:

1. **Triggering Azure App Configuration Refresh**:
   Your configuration setup specifies which settings to watch and when to trigger a refresh, but you still need to periodically invoke this refresh. The method `ConfigureRefresh` sets up the potential for refreshing, but doesn't schedule it.
2. **Understanding `IsEnabledAsync`**:
   This method checks the feature flag value from the cache. If the cache isn't refreshed, you'll get the cached (and possibly outdated) value, even if the underlying value in Azure App Configuration has changed.

**Suggested Fixes**:

1. **Use a Hosted Service**:
   Implement a hosted service in ASP.NET Core to periodically refresh your Azure App Configuration. This service can be set to run at intervals and invoke the refresh.

```cs
public class AzureAppConfigRefreshService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRefresher _configurationRefresher;
    private Timer _timer;

    public AzureAppConfigRefreshService(IConfigurationRefresher configurationRefresher)
    {
        _configurationRefresher = configurationRefresher;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void DoWork(object state)
    {
        await _configurationRefresher.TryRefreshAsync();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can add this hosted service to your services in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AzureAppConfigRefreshService>();
```

2. **Ensure Correct Key**:
   Make sure that the key you're registering for refresh matches exactly with the key in Azure App Configuration.
3. **Ensure Timely Calls to `IsEnabledAsync`**:
   Ensure that `IsEnabledAsync` is invoked after the configuration has been refreshed to get the latest value.

Lastly, do note that this approach involves external calls every minute. Be mindful of any potential costs or rate limits associated with excessive requests to Azure App Configuration. Adjust the refresh interval as necessary.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a helpful and well documented answer. Thank you for your time.